# Store variable at certain memory address C#

Tags: c#, memory

I want to make a program which stores the value at a given static memory address (for example 0x1F2), so that I can later Readprocessmemory from this address using another program and get the variable value.

How can I do that in .net and C#?

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve? There are better inter process communication techniques available.

Comment: What would these techniques be?

Comment: NamedPipes, Memory mapped files, sockets, wcf, msmq, etc. Choose whichever suits you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hard-coding a specific memory address, you can use Memory Mapped Files to share a portion of memory between processes.

There's more information on MSDN here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx